# Return of list of strings using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My function filters and return labels from two pandas series contingent on a couple of conditions. Although my code works, the output is a class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index', instead of class 'set' as required.

My code is as follows:

```
def find_outliers(ks_values, p_values, ks_threshold, pvalue_threshold=0.05):

"""
Find outlying symbols using KS values and P-values

Parameters
----------
ks_values : Pandas Series
    KS static for all the tickers
p_values : Pandas Series
    P value for all the tickers
ks_threshold : float
    The threshold for the KS statistic
pvalue_threshold : float
    The threshold for the p-value

Returns
-------
outliers : set of str
    Symbols that are outliers
"""
# Function Implementation


Symbols_ks = pd.Series(index=ks_values.index)
Symbols_pval = pd.Series(index=p_values.index)

Symbols_ks = list(ks_values[ks_values> ks_threshold].index.values)
Symbols_pval = list(p_values[p_values< pvalue_threshold].index.values)

outliers = set(Symbols_ks.extend(Symbols_pval)) 

return outliers
```

Series1 and Series2 include labels with corresponding values in the following form:

```
ADBE    0.24268
ADI     0.19429
ADM     0.18128
ADP     0.17243
ADS     0.24109
ADSK    0.14591
AEE     0.18874
```

My objective is to return a list of labels conditional on exceeding (or not) both thresholds. The output must be a set of strings.

Apologies if some would find my query rather simple. Many thanks.

Comment: change the name of your variable, `list` is a reserved word

Comment: I used the name list for the example, suppose the variable is named plist instead. My function returns a class pandas.core.indexes.base.Index instead of a class ‘set’.

Comment: we help based on what you provide, if your example doesn't match the actual code you're running you're just wasting people's time and that is not good for the community.

Comment: No harm intended. The naming convention has been changed. The code is conform with what I am running. Any advice? Gracias

Comment: Thank you. There appear to be an assertion error: Wrong type for output plist. Got <class 'NoneType'>, expected <class 'set'>

Comment: The function is meant to return a python list of unique tickers that meet the imposed criteria. So when we isolate the index, this needs to be transformed to a list. Then one needs to return set(list) to give the unique outliers - I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I' m running

```
def find_outliers(ks_values, p_values, ks_threshold, pvalue_threshold=0.05):
    Symbols_ks = pd.Series(index=ks_values.index)
    Symbols_pval = pd.Series(index=p_values.index)

    Symbols_ks = list(ks_values[ks_values> ks_threshold].index.values)
    Symbols_pval = list(p_values[p_values< pvalue_threshold].index.values)

    Symbols_ks.extend(Symbols_pval)

    return set(Symbols_ks)
```

#### Test (using sample data from the comments)

```
find_outliers(a,b,0.5)
```

Output:

```
{IBID}
```

Comment: I get the following TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: share the actual code that is generating that error. Since you're new we tend to be tolerant with first questions but you need to understand that your question does not provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and failing to do so is usually an immediate downvote of your question

Comment: I am running the above function using the following parameters:        
    ks_values: 
    HPNM    0.20326939
    ZXGG    0.34826827
    IBID    0.60256811
    dtype: float64 
 ------------------
    p_values: 
    HPNM    0.98593727
    ZXGG    0.48009144
    IBID    0.02898631
   dtype: float64 
 -------------
ks_threshold: 0.5

Comment: ks_values and p_values are long lists, the code shows me values for 3 rows at a time..

Comment: Hmm.. still same error           
<ipython-input-60-bf5764de5e8e> in find_outliers(ks_values, p_values, ks_threshold, pvalue_threshold)
     
29     Symbols_pval = list(p_values[p_values< pvalue_threshold].index.values)
 30 
---> 31     outliers = set(Symbols_ks.extend(Symbols_pval))
     32 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. It doesn't like 'set(Symbols_ks.extend(Symbols_pval))' for some reason

Comment: it took us a while haha, but we made it

Comment: we sure did, thanks to you :) I clicked on the vote button a few times. Apparently stackoverflow recorded my vote, however it does not display it because I have less than 15 reputation..

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a slightly different way for the computation

```
r = (ks_values > ks_threshold).combine(p_values < pvalue_threshold, lambda x,y: x & y)
s = set(r[r == True].index.values)
```